# Delete row in Google Sheets that contains any number of defined keywords

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to delete rows in Google Sheets that contain any keyword that is a member of some pre-defined set.  I currently have the following code:

```
function removeKeywords() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
 var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
 var values = rows.getValues();

 var rowsDeleted = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

 var row = values[i];

 if (row[0].indexOf("admin","conference","department") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 }
};
```

Where the keywords 'admin', 'conference', and 'department' trigger the function to delete the row.  Yet my code doesn't work.  Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
 function removeKeywords() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var rowsDeleted = 0;
 sheet.getDataRange()
     .getValues()
     .forEach(function (r, i) {
         if (["admin", "conference", "department"].indexOf(r[0]) > -1) {
             sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i) + 1) - rowsDeleted);
             rowsDeleted++;
         }
     })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, JPV, but that doesn't seem to work.  Another thing I've tried is to just create a series as follows but I think that this is hugely inefficient:


 if (row[0].indexOf("department") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 if (row[0].indexOf("conference") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 if (row[0].indexOf("admin") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

Comment: `if (row[0].indexOf("department") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 if (row[0].indexOf("conference") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }

 if (row[0].indexOf("admin") > -1) {
 sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
 rowsDeleted++;
 }`

Comment: Yep, here is the link:

https://docs.google.com/a/editing.press/spreadsheets/d/1ieWzLB7-wldA9xsFVZFCLvd-bpufWUn1BmLqJd15fsc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Apologies, I think the permissions of the sheet weren't right. I think I have corrected this but please let me know. 

I have added a version of the 'inefficient code' script, which works, but I think that this might cause problems if we have, for example, 100 keywords that we want to activate the delete row function.

Comment: Any clues, @JPV?

Comment: I have noticed that the suggested code works in one sheet but not another.  I.e., in the test sheet I created, the code you suggested worked, but did not work once I transposed it to the sheet in which I actually need it to work.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @EdPress: can't access your sheet. Please fix.